# Wordpress HTTP 500 on theme change

Tags: wordpress, themes, init

i just:

1. moved a remote wp network installation to local (mamp). everything fine.
2. installed a new theme. everything fine.
3. activated the new theme. doh!

i started going through the code and i found that it doesn't fix it, but at least i got a nice-relaxing-blank-white-page, if i remove the *do_action( 'init' );* from **wp-settings.php**.

i googled a while and i found that "*Your problem is probably wp_cron being called by init. In 2.1 and up, the cron process is called externally, so one thing that could be your problem is the DNS resolution not working on your webserver to find its own address.*"… i don't know if this could be the right answer to my issue, what am i supposed to do to fix it all?

ty!

Comment: it could be any number of things triggering the error. can you check your error log for more details about the error? is it a theme you've succesfully used in the past? are you using any plugins? are you using the most recent version of wordpress?

Comment: oooooooooh old-shit-version running -_-"

Comment: ty mate, sometimes you spend hours looking for they keys you got in your hand…

Answer (score 1):

To determine what the actual error is, you will want to turn on debugging. To do this, add the following line to your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

It should then start spitting out lots of textual data as to what the error is. In all likelihood, it is a PHP error due to a coding issue (bad function call, missing end tag, etc.) in the new theme, or a difference in configuration between your live site and MAMP setup.

For more info on WordPress debugging, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress.